# How should I install a Python module in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I downloaded the `cosmolopy` Python library and tried to install it in every possible way...

Finally, I saved Cosmolopy as `c:\python27\Lib\cosmolopy\...`

1 Then run the setup file which gives me error

2 Run the following command form command prompt

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

BUT AGAIN GIVES ME **ERROR**: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

PLEASE HELP ME OUT IT'S TALKING A LOT OF TIME IN INSTALLING MODULE

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat and install Visual Studio to compile the c-code to a binary that python can use.

Comment: Installed successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just put it in the same folder as your project.

EG:

```
Some_Directory\  
   python_file.py
   The_module.py
```